# Como mostrar datos de un ArrayList en un Jtable

Tags: java

> ```
> public class Reproductor extends javax.swing.JFrame {
>
>     public ArrayList<Proceso> ArrayLista;
>     public ListIterator<Proceso> ListaIterator;
>     DefaultListModel modelo = new DefaultListModel();
>     DefaultTableModel mitabla = new DefaultTableModel();
>     int cantidad;
>
>     /**
>      * Creates new form Reproductor
>      */
>     public Reproductor() {
>         initComponents();
>         ArrayLista = new ArrayList<>();
>         cantidad = 0;
>         jmusica.setModel(mitabla);
>         ArrayLista.add(new Proceso("My Hero"));
>     }
>
> private void btnmostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
> {                                           
>         // BTN MOSTRAR
>
>         cantidad = ArrayLista.size();
>         ListaIterator = ArrayLista.listIterator();
>         Proceso dato;
>
>         while(ListaIterator.hasNext()){
>             dato = ListaIterator.next();
>             mitabla.addRow(dato.getNombremusica());
>             jmusica.setModel(mitabla);
>         }
> ```

Ingreso `mitabla.addRow(dato.getNombremusica());` y aparece error, ¿cuál
 puede ser el problema ?

Comment: No sé si te funcionará, pero yo cuando he tenido que pasar los datos de una colección a una  tabla primero los he pasado a un String[][] para luego pasar la matriz al model. Aquí viene una explicación: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Seguro que hay formas más eficientes, pero hasta ahí mis conocimientos, un saludo.

Comment: @thelaw que error aparece, es importante agregarlo a tu pregunta.